# Encoding issue in shapefile character column

Tags: r, encoding, character-encoding, shapefile

I am trying to read a shapefile (available in [this folder](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9Y4uonCUmT7NGQ2Q1pJMVAxMm8/view?resourcekey=0-lslvZiLNaRKTRxGHYRDXOA)) in R, but have not been able to solve a codification issue in one of the columns.

If I load it using `sf`, I get, from one of the observations, `BanabuiÃº` instead of `Barnabuiú`:

```
library(sf)
shape <- st_read("/shapefiles/amc_1872_2010.shp")
shape$NOME_MUNIC[2]
```

Of course, the problem happens everytime I should have an accent or a ç.

Ideally, I would either transform this full column into a readable UTF-8 format, or remove all accents, to allow the merge with another municipality dataset.  Unfortunately, this has not been possible.  I alternatively tried the `stringi::iconv` to make things work (and the `rgdal::readOGR(., encoding = "UTF-8")`, but the results are not satisfying.  Encoding detecting tools (like [this](https://dencode.com/en/)) did not solve my problem.  I wonder if the problem comes from the shapefile itself or the importation of it.

Thank you.

Comment: The issue is caused by the shapefile(s) itself. Per default, shapefile has ISO-8859-1 encoding (see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3529/which-character-encoding-is-used-by-the-dbf-file-in-shapefiles). The linked shapefile, opened in qgis, shows NOME_MUNIC like `Abadia de GoiÃ¡s` for example. So, I do believe there is no issue with {sf} itself, rather with input data.